# Showing $A^2 - 3A^{147} + 2I = \begin{pmatrix} 9 & -9\\ 3 & -3\end{pmatrix}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $ A = $$ \begin{pmatrix} 9 & -9\\ 3 & -3\end{pmatrix} $$ $. Show
$$A^2 - 3A^{147} + 2I =  \begin{pmatrix} 9 & -9\\ 3 & -3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I'd start by taking powers of $A$ to see if there's a pattern. If I spot one, I'd (most likely) prove it's there by induction then use it to calculate $A^{147}$. The solution should then be straightforward.

Comment: Also, please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: The given equation is not fulfilled.

Comment: @Shaun Alright I will keep induction constantly in my mind from now on seeing it's needed in a lot of exercises. If you mean how I like the site so far, it's great but I still need to get used to LaTeX.

Comment: Actually, I meant your thoughts on the problem so far. Some people downvote questions that don't have any signs of effort on the part of the person asking. Regardless, I'm glad you like it so far. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'm not very comfortable showing my math thought processes to the public so far :P But yeah when I first saw the problem I was trying to find a connection between the powers. However, I completely ignored the given matrix at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write $A$ as $A=3B$ where $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -3\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, you can compute easily that $B^2=2B$ and so by induction you'll have $B^n=2^{n-1}B$.
Therefore $A^n=(3B)^n=3^n\times2^{n-1}B=6^{n-1}A$. I am sure from this point you can find what you wanted, can't you?

Comment: Yes I've solved it a while ago but I can't accept a comment as an answer because it doesn't let me, so I'll just accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Once you compute the characteristic polynomial you get $\lambda^2-6\lambda=0$. Thus $A^2-6A=O$.
Therefore $A^{n}=6^{n-1}A$. See if you can proceed from here.

Comment: Oh I can't use eigenvalues to compute this yet :) Not because I don't know them but because I'm trying to solve some exercises which are before the chapter of eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Comment: In that case just compute $A^2$ and see what happens.It will be easy for you to spot that $A^2=6A$.